# How can I make case-statement in a lib/Module method more DRY in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, case

The following is in a method in a lib/Module I have called cron_tasks.rb.

It is in a case statement:

```
case quad

when "0"
```

Then this type of code is run.

```
79           #upper-left address
 80            pdf.draw_text contact.first_name + " " + contact.last_name,
 81               :at =>[(pdf.bounds.left + postcard_width - in2pt(2.75)), (pdf.bounds.top - in2pt(2.25))],
 82               :size => 14
 83 
 84            pdf.draw_text contact.address.street1,
 85               :at =>[(pdf.bounds.left + postcard_width - in2pt(2.75)), (pdf.bounds.top - in2pt(2.25) - 20)],
 86               :size => 14
 87 
 88            pdf.draw_text contact.address.city + ", " + contact.address.state,
 89               :at =>[(pdf.bounds.left + postcard_width - in2pt(2.75)), (pdf.bounds.top - in2pt(2.25) - 40)],
 90               :size => 14
 91 
 92            pdf.draw_text contact.address.zip,
 93               :at =>[(pdf.bounds.left + postcard_width - in2pt(2.75)), (pdf.bounds.top - in2pt(2.25) - 60)],
 94               :size => 14
```

There is only a slight offset of all this code for the different when's:

```
when 1
....(same code)

when 2
....(same code)

when 3
....(same code)
```

Is there a way to make all that text-positioning more DRY (perhaps self.position in this module?) so that I can just pass the offsets?

I am printing addresses, four at a time, on a large sheet of paper so the relative location is the same, I just need to move it to each of the four quadrants.

**Important:  the hard challenge is that when I tried to use self.print_address I had to pass so many variables from the main method...in fact, I haven't been able to figure out how to add all of them because there are dependencies on other modules...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Bounding Boxes. Instead of absolute positioning every address line, you could just absolute position the four bounding boxes.

```
  pdf.bounding_box([(pdf.bounds.left + postcard_width - in2pt(2.75)), (pdf.bounds.top - in2pt(2.25))], :width=>250, :height=>100) do
     pdf.font_size 14
     pdf.text contact.first_name + " " + contact.last_name
     pdf.text contact.address.street1
     pdf.text contact.address.city + ", " + contact.address.state
     pdf.text contact.address.zip
     #pdf.stroke_bounds #use for testing box size
  end
```

**EDIT: using with lambda**

wrap the bounding box in a lamba then call that from your case statement.

```
draw_address = lambda { |contact, x, y| 
  pdf.bounding_box([x, y], :width=>250, :height=>100) do
     pdf.font_size 14
     pdf.text contact.first_name + " " + contact.last_name
     pdf.text contact.address.street1
     pdf.text contact.address.city + ", " + contact.address.state
     pdf.text contact.address.zip
     #pdf.stroke_bounds #use for testing box size
  end
  }

  #use draw_address in your case to populate and position
when 1
  draw_address(contact, 560, 70)
when 2
  draw_address(contact, 240, 70)
when etc...
```

Comment: Okay...how do I do the offset for each of the four quadrants?

Comment: It looks like for each quadrant, I would still need to retype the above in the bounding_box but with a different [x,y]...how can I make that more DRY?

Comment: there is only 4 different positions to enter, so I would wrap the bounding box in a lamba block like 'mu is too short' explains in his answer. then just have the position pass into it e.g. draw_it.call(contact, x, y)

Comment: How do I pass the offset values for each quadrant, I'm not clear, it look slike there is only a single offset value.  And how would I place this in the context of my four separate case statements?

Comment: @Angela - I Have added how to use the bounding box with a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the repeated stuff in a lambda, that would make the differences instantly obvious and you'd avoid repeating yourself:

```
draw_it = lambda { |str, offset|
    x = pdf.bounds.left + postcard_width - in2pt(2.75)
    y = pdf.bounds.top  - in2pt(2.25)    - offset
    pdf.draw_text(str, :at =>[ x, y ], :size => 14)
}
#...
draw_it.call(contact.first_name + " " + contact.last_name,         0)
draw_it.call(contact.address.street1,                             20)
draw_it.call(contact.address.city + ", " + contact.address.state, 40)
draw_it.call(contact.address.zip,                                 60)
```

Then one more simple step to do away with the `offset` parameter:

```
offset  = 0
draw_it = lambda { |str|
    x       = pdf.bounds.left + postcard_width - in2pt(2.75)
    y       = pdf.bounds.top  - in2pt(2.25)    - offset
    offset += 20
    pdf.draw_text(str, :at =>[ x, y ], :size => 14)
}
#...
draw_it.call(contact.first_name + " " + contact.last_name)
draw_it.call(contact.address.street1)
draw_it.call(contact.address.city + ", " + contact.address.state)
draw_it.call(contact.address.zip)
```

You could also make this a full blown method but then you'd have to properly track and reset the value of `@offset` and you'd end up with dragging a mostly useless instance variable (`@offset`) around; a simple closure probably makes more sense for a case like this.

Comment: I see...but how do I place it for each 'when' in the case statement for each 'quadrant' on the sheet of paper (imagine upper-left, lower-left, etcetera).....

Comment: how do I pass the four different quadrant values and not have to rewrite the code in each when statement?